Windows ldap apache authentication and Typo3
I've got a problem with a site after ldap authentication.
Windows server with apache - httpd-ssl.conf:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin web@test.de
    DocumentRoot "E:/Intranet/testpage/"
    ServerName testpage
    ErrorLog "logs/ourproject.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/ourproject-access.log" common
    
    <Location />
        Require host testpage
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "USE YOUR WINDOWS ACCOUNT"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        Require valid-user
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=test,OU=Service-Accounts,OU=Administration,DC=test,DC=dc"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ad-server.test.dc/ou=Region_MSR,dc=test,dc=dc?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    </Location>
        
#    <Directory E:/Intranet/test-intern/>      
#         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
#         AllowOverride AuthConfig
#    </Directory>
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/test.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/test.pem"
   
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    
    CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost> 

The apache server hosts a multi-domain typo3-site. All domains are accessible but one - it's protected by ldap authentication, which works.
But after successfull AD-login, I get an internal server error - other domains from the same installation work fine.
Error-Log: [ldap:error] [pid 3580:tid 1500] (70023)This function has not been 
implemented on this platform: AH01277: LDAP: Unable to add rebind cross 
reference entry. Out of memory?

Inserting "LDAPReferrals Off" results in
Not Found
The requested URL /aktuelles was not found on this server.
Tried also with alias, which didn't work.
https://serverfault.com/questions/1014397/apache-authentication-fails-with-require-ldap-group
Any suggestions!
Thanks a lot!

This works, but I don't know  - is it secure?
With  LDAPReferrals Off  within location section and
<Directory /test/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require all granted

AllowOverride AuthConfig doesn't work ...

Though Require valid user works, I've got  - I guess - the same problem with allowOverride with htacces and require ldap group - after Login - internal server error
